# How to convert all merged remote git branches to tags? (create tags, delete branches)

Tags: linux, git

(Before I use giltab's `delete merged branches` feature 
(see
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/branches/#delete-merged-branches ) - I want to tag them - in case I'll need to reference them in future.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(on linux:)

## how to tag all merged remote git branches in bulk

```
git branch --remotes --merged |
grep --invert-match --perl-regexp "^  origin/(HEAD ->|master$)" |
sed "s#^  origin/##g" |
xargs -I {} \
git push origin origin/{}:refs/tags/merged/{}
```

- `git branch` - list all remote merged branches
- `grep` - exclude head, master from the list
- `sed` - remove the `origin/` prefix from branch names
- `xargs -I` execute a following command one time for each line got from previous command
  (replacing every occurrence of `{}` with the name of a branch)
- `git push` - tag remote branch with `merged/<branch-name>` tag

after that, remote merged branches may be deleted since they're no longer needed anymore.

### how to update local copies of remote tags & branches after the remote ones were added/deleted

```
git fetch --tags --prune
```

- `--prune` will delete local copies of remote branches that no more exist in remote repo
- `--tags`'ll fetch tags created in previous section